# Link click calls controller and opens a new tab - jQuery & ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have such a link

```
<a href="#" id="mylink">click here</a>
```

And when user clicks the link AJAX works like this :

```
$('#mylink').click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault(); 

   //call the MVC controller so that the controller creates the PDF file.
   });
});
```

What I want to do is, when the link is clicked and the controller generates the PDF file, the generated PDF file should be opened in new tab of the browser. How should I modify my code to do that? Thanks.

Comment: How is the PDF file served? Assuming it's available from a URL, return that URL from the AJAX call, then redirect to it in JS

Comment: something like `<a href="@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { id = 1 })" target="_blank")">Download</a>` should do the job, no jQuery required I don't think. Or Html.ActionLink would generate the entire link for you, in fact